# PostgreSQL не верное отображение символов

Tags: postgresql

Установил PostgreSQL и запускаю SQL Shell. Вводя любую команду, которая выводит кириллические символы они получаются закорючками. Что делать?

```
    ╚ь     | ┬ырфхыхЎ | ╩юфшЁютър |         LC_COLLATE         |          LC_CTYPE          |     ╧Ёртр фюёЄєяр
-----------+----------+-----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8      | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 |
 template0 | postgres | UTF8      | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |           |                            |                            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8      | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |           |                            |                            | postgres=CTc/postgres
(3 ёЄЁюъш)
```

Comment: шелл выводит в win1251, а консоль по умолчанию ibm866. поменяйте настройки cmd

Answer (score 0):

Ответ от @Sergey Tatarincev

> шелл выводит в win1251, а консоль по умолчанию ibm866. поменяйте настройки cmd ```